# How can i push one branch in diffeent remote repo in git

Tags: git, version-control

I am working on a project where we have one master branch and locally we have separate branch called  `testing`

Currenty i can only push to master branch and my team lead told me not to push my branch on remote repo server.

This is my git config

```
 [core]
  2     repositoryformatversion = 0
  3     filemode = true
  4     bare = false
  5     logallrefupdates = true
  6 [remote "origin"]
  7     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  8     url = https://user@mydomain/myrepo
  9 [branch "master"]
 10     remote = origin
 11     merge = refs/heads/master
 12 [user]
 13     email = xxxx
 14     name = xxxxx
```

Is there any way that i can also link this project to my other remote repo on bitbucket so that i can also push my branch changes to bitbucket.

Also can i have both `master` and `testing` branch commits on bitbucket and my company server as well

Comment: I have no answer, but I would make very well sure that your company doesn't have a problem with you hosting the code outside their servers. 99% of companies would have a very big problem with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding another remote repo is simple, however, as [Chris Hayes points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862757/how-can-i-push-one-branch-in-diffeent-remote-repo-in-git#comment27834814_18862757), you should check to see if this is okay with your company first.

Assuming that it's OK, you simply add the remote url for the BitBucket repository, and push to it:

```
git remote add bitbucket <bitbucket-repo-url>
git push bitbucket master testing
```